# My code displays nothing after pressing the Login button in user verification

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt

Here right below is my code for Login user interface. I am trying to create a user verification. I have done everything I was supposed to do but my code doesn't display anything after pressing Login button in the console. What's wrong with this code?

```
import javax.swing.*;                              // For Frame
import java.awt.event.*;                           // For action Listener
import java.sql.*;                                // For Database

public class Login {
    /*    Three instance varaibles     */

    Connection con;
    Statement st;
    ResultSet rs;
    JFrame f = new JFrame("User Login");
    JLabel l = new JLabel("Username:");
    JLabel l1 = new JLabel("Password:");
    JTextField t = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField t1 = new JTextField(10);
    JButton b = new JButton("Login");

    /*     CONSTRUCTOR                 */
    public Login() {
        /*    METHODS                */
        connect();
        frame();
    }

    public void connect() {
        try {
            /*         DECLARING DRIVER                             */
            String driver = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";
            Class.forName(driver);
            String db = "jdbc:odbc:Database1";
            /*  THIS WILL GET A CONNECTION TO OUR DATABASE  */
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(db);
            st = con.createStatement();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
    }

    public void frame() {
        f.setSize(600, 400);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.add(l);
        p.add(t);
        p.add(l1);
        p.add(t1);
        p.add(b);
        f.add(p);
        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    String user = t.getText().trim();
                    String pass = t1.getText().trim();
                    String sql = "select user,pass from Table2 where user='"
                            + user + "'and pass='" + pass + "'";
                    rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
                    int count = 0;
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        count = count + 1;
                    }
                    if (count == 1) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                                "User found, Access granted! ");
                    } else if (count > 1) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                                "Duplicate user, Access denied! ");
                    } else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                                "User not found! ");
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Login();
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you expect to happen after you hit login?

Comment: Print the Exception in catch block.. `System.out.println(ex);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Put a `System.out.println("Driver Loaded")` after `Class.forName()` to see if the driver is loaded
2. Put a `System.out.printlnt("Connected to Database")` after the connection code to see if its connected
3. Put `ex.printStackTrace()` in all you empty catch blocks so you can see where the error is occurring.
4. I forgot to add my MySql jar when testing this out so I got a `ClassNotFoundException`. Make sure you include your jar in the project. After I added the jar, the code works. I did switch the database to MySql though, since that's the one I use

Adding on to number 3. If you get a `ClassNotFoundExceptio` you probably need to add your driver jar to your library. If you get `SQLException` either something is wrong with your connection syntax or your query syntax. Other than that I don't where else an exception would occur, as I ran it myself.

Answer (score 1):

Three things come to mind.  The first, which has already being highlighted, is to not blindly consume exceptions

```
try
{
    String driver = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";
    Class.forName(driver);

    String db = "jdbc:odbc:Database1";
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(db);
    st = con.createStatement();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    // This is a bad idea...
}
```

You should avoid catching "all" exceptions and instead focus on those that are known to be thrown.

At the very least, you should be logging the exception in some way and/or re-throwing or raising a new exception so that the caller knows that something went wrong

Secondly, you are making the window visible before you've added anything to it...

```
f.setSize(600, 400);
f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
f.setVisible(true);

JPanel p = new JPanel();
p.add(l);
p.add(t);
p.add(l1);
p.add(t1);
p.add(b);
//...
```

Instead, you should prepare the UI and then make it visible...

```
f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

JPanel p = new JPanel();
p.add(l);
p.add(t);
p.add(l1);
p.add(t1);
p.add(b);
//...
f.pack();
f.setVisible(true);
```

Thirdly, you are not starting you UI within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread which could lead to all sorts of additional weirdness in the long run...

```
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.add(l);
        p.add(t);
        p.add(l1);
        p.add(t1);
        p.add(b);
        //...
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

See [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be throwing an exception during execution. Could be with your database related code. You are entering the catch block in your code and there is nothing done there. Print the stack trace to check the error.

```
 catch (Exception ex) {
     ex.printStackTrace (); 
 }
```

Adding the following line in both exception blocks, shows the message "error!" on the panel which means that your panel related code is working fine.

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "error! ");
```